# How does one make symbols that refer to structure slots in lisp?

Tags: binary-tree, common-lisp, symbols

I am self learning lisp and thought a nice non-trivial program would be to write a set of standard tree insertion and manipulation routines.  I figured it could be done with CONS but wanted to try it with a structure.

I put together one version that worked:

```
(defstruct treenode data left right)

(defun tree-insert ( value tree )
"Insert data into tree"
(if tree
  (if (< value (treenode-data tree))
       (setf (treenode-left tree) (tree-insert value (treenode-left tree)))
       (setf (treenode-right tree) (tree-insert value (treenode-right tree))))
  (setf tree (make-treenode :data value)))
tree)
```

which rebuilt the tree at every step which seemed computationally inefficient.  By inefficient, I mean that I have to use setf every time I do another level of recursion. So I wanted to try a scheme that passed the tree by reference rather than by value so I could make assignments in the subroutine that inserts into a tree.

I cobbled the following together, which does not work (but give me credit for having comments):

```
(defstruct treenode data left right)

(defun tree-insert ( value tree )
"Insert data value into tree, using pass by reference.

value  A datum to insert, in this version has to be a number.
tree   The tree passed as a symbol."  

(setq tval (symbol-value tree))
(if (eq tval nil)
  (set tree (make-treenode :data value))          ; Empty tree. Place data here.
  (if (< value (treenode-data tval))              ; Non-empty node.  Decide which subtree for insert.
      (tree-insert value (treenode-left tval))    ; Left side
      (tree-insert value (treenode-right tval)))) ; Right side.  This is a stable sort.   
nil)

? (setf tr nil)
NIL
? (tree-insert 10 'tr)
NIL
? tr
#S(TREENODE :DATA 10 :LEFT NIL :RIGHT NIL)
?
```

The initial insert works fine.  Passing a symbol the (set tree ...) correctly inserts the structure with left and right porinters nil.

Of course, the problem that follows is that on the recursive call to  tree-insert I am not passing a symbol.

That is the hangup.  I haven't found a way to refer to a structure slot as a symbol that I can then pass to tree-insert.

I've been looking around for a couple of days and found this interesting comment about the defstruct macro: "defstruct not only defines an access function for each slot, but also arranges for setf to work properly on such access functions, defines a predicate named name-p, defines a constructor function named make-name, and defines a copier function named copy-name. All names of automatically created functions are interned in whatever package is current at the time the defstruct form is processed (see *package*). Also, all such functions may be declared inline at the discretion of the implementation to improve efficiency; if you do not want some function declared inline, follow the defstruct form with a notinline declaration to override any automatic inline declaration."

So, what could I do to do the magic that setf does? I know I can do assignments to slots with setf, but I haven't gotten setf to work in a function due to lexical scope rules.  Maybe like adding automatic functions to allow symbol generating, like (treenode-data-symbol tr)?

Of course, lisp programmers have dealt with binary trees since before my first PDP-8/L. What's the lispy way to do this?

This is an edited question.  User Rainer Joswig gave a very fast and concise response.  I learned a lot from the example he gave. I was interested in the issue of modifying the tree directly rather than using a return value from a function.

From the comments I've seen here, and the one answer by Rainer Joswig, should I draw the conclusion that the pointer manipulation is computationally low in cost, and that the best lisp approach is to use a function that returns a tree rather than relying on an approach of modifying the argument?

Comment: You shouldn't use symbols at all for this. It's a dead end. Use the structure objects directly. `(setf (treenode-left foo) bar)` sets a slot of a structure object to the value of `bar`.

Comment: `(setq tval ...)` sets a global undefined variable. Probably not what you want? Use `let` or others to define local variables. `setq` only sets variables, but does not define them.

Comment: props for the comments, deductions for the lack of indentation. :)

Comment: it's OK to pass in the tree structure as an argument. when `(setf (treenode-left tree) ...)` is called inside the function, it will actually change the value of the slot in the original `tree` structure. It is a *mutable* value.

Comment: I realize I misled.  I previously had figured out how to write the tree insertion when I realized that local scope didn't let me modify the tree in the subroutine, and I needed to return the subtree at each step and use setf on each return.  So I edited the question, which I hope is a better question of modification of an argument.  From the comments I think the deeper answer is that the benefit of a functional approach call for returning of subtrees at each level of recursion.  BTW thanks for editors with (> (+ rep-rainer rep-will) 200000) gave this older beginner a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With much thanks to Rainer and Will, I understand Common Lisp better, now.  The point about not having first class pointers is huge. I don't have to keep looking for that anymore, though I did see a package that implemented refs in my searches.

The key problem in my approach was that I defined an empty tree as nil.  Since passing nil doesn't allow any manipulation of the argument, nil being immutable, the algorithm was bound to fail.

Redefining the empty tree as '(nil) allows the program to work.

```
;; Make list of 5 random numbers.
(setf r5 (loop for i from 1 to 5 collect (random 100)))

;; Initialize tr to empty tree.
;; Empty tree is '(nil). Tree with data is '(data left right),
;; where left and right are either empty tree or tree with data.
(setf tr '(nil))

(defun tree-insert ( value tree )
  "Insert data into tree. tree is modified with an insertion."
  (if (equal tree '(nil))
      (progn                ; Empty (sub)tree.  Insert value.
        (setf (car tree) value)
        (setf (cdr tree) (list (list nil)(list nil))))
      (progn                ; Non-empty subtree.
        (if (< value (car tree))
              (tree-insert value (second tree))    ; Insert on left.
              (tree-insert value (third tree)))))  ; Insert on right.
  nil)

;; Load tree with the list of random numbers defined above.
(mapc (lambda (val) (tree-insert val tr)) r5)

(defun tree-walk (tree)
"Retrieve keys in sorted order."
  (if (car tree) 
      (progn
        (tree-walk (second tree))     ; Left subtree.
        (format t " ~d" (car tree))
        (tree-walk (third tree)))))   ; Right subtree.

;; Walk the tree.
(tree-walk tr)
```

Example in use:

```
? (setf r5 (loop for i from 1 to 5 collect (random 100)))
(22 50 76 20 49)
? (setf tr '(nil))
(NIL)
? (mapc (lambda (val) (tree-insert val tr)) r5)
;Compiler warnings :
;   In an anonymous lambda form at position 37: Undeclared free variable TR
(22 50 76 20 49)
? tr
(22 (20 (NIL) (NIL)) (50 (49 (NIL) (NIL)) (76 (NIL) (NIL))))
? (tree-walk tr)
 20 22 49 50 76
NIL
?
```

So, several things to make this work. A mutable object has to be passed to the procedure.  In this case I redesigned the structure to be a list, either '(nil) for empty, or '(data left right), where left and right are either '(nil) or '(data left right). A list containing nil can be manipulated. However, I had to use car and cdr to access the structure so as to preserve Lisp's pointer that was passed to the procedure.

Another thing I had to do was not use a list constant in the functon definitions.  I'm sure knowledgeable people will be in the know about this, and chucle a bit about the opaque error that follow until the issue is understood, but if I had used '((nil)(nil)) rather than (list (list nil)(list nil)) in tree-insert it would not work.  Looks like Lisp compiles list shorthand notation to a pointer to an abject in memory which is used on all subsequent calls of the function.

Oh, there is a leftover progn function call in tree-insert.  That was from when I wrapped everything with progn to let me add print statements during debugging.

Running timing on the functions was interesting.  It's fast! I'll run some timing comparisons to compare the functional reassignment approach vs the search and insert algorithms.

Thanks, again, to the expert comments.  Since last contributing I've learned a little about map, loop/collect, and that variables leak out of functions into global space when let isn't used in function definitions. Also wrapping a funciton with a lot of output with (progn ... nil) saves screen space after large data structures are used. I have learned a lot with just this exercise.

Answer (score 6):

simple version for your inspiration:

```
(defstruct node a b v)

(defun insert-tree (tree value)
  (cond ((null tree)
         (setf tree (make-node :v value)))
        ((> (node-v tree)
            value)
         (setf (node-a tree)
               (insert-tree (node-a tree) value)))
        (t
         (setf (node-b tree)
               (insert-tree (node-b tree) value))))
  tree)
```

using it:

```
CL-USER 171 > (let ((tree nil))
                (loop for i in '(4 7 3 5 9 10 11 8)
                      do (setf tree (insert-tree tree i)))
                (pprint tree)
                (values))

#S(NODE :A #S(NODE :A NIL :B NIL :V 3)
        :B #S(NODE :A #S(NODE :A NIL :B NIL :V 5)
                   :B #S(NODE :A #S(NODE :A NIL :B NIL :V 8)
                              :B #S(NODE :A NIL
                                         :B #S(NODE :A NIL
                                                    :B NIL
                                                    :V 11)
                                         :V 10)
                              :V 9)
                   :V 7)
        :V 4)
```

Now, if wanted to do less `setf` operations, we could check whether the returned subtree is the same which we passed. This will only not be the case when we create a new node.

```
(defun insert-tree (tree value)
  (cond ((null tree)
         (setf tree (make-node :v value)))
        ((> (node-v tree)
            value)
         (let ((new-tree (insert-tree (node-a tree) value)))
           (unless (eql new-tree (node-a tree))
             (setf (node-a tree) new-tree))))
        (t
         (setf (node-b tree)
               (insert-tree (node-b tree) value))))
  tree)
```

or with a local macro hiding part of the code:

```
(defun insert-tree (tree value)
  (macrolet ((insert (place call &aux (new-value-sym (gensym "new-value")))
               `(let ((,new-value-sym ,call))
                  (unless (eql ,place ,new-value-sym)
                    (setf ,place ,new-value-sym)))))
    (cond ((null tree)
           (setf tree (make-node :v value)))
          ((> (node-v tree)
              value)
           (insert (node-a tree) (insert-tree (node-a tree) value)))
          (t
           (insert (node-b tree) (insert-tree (node-b tree) value))))
    tree))
```

Comment: Oh, that I figured out. What I wanted to know was if there is a way to walk the tree and just do one assignment when the insertion location is found.  I've edited the question.  HOWEVER, wow, I'm humbled by the elegance of your fuction version, the use of the cond function, the null test, and the example of the loop with let to wrap it, and the pprint. I learned a lot just from the example you gave!

Answer (score 4):

Trying to add an answer from another angle.

In standard Common Lisp structures have a bunch of limitations to make them low-level and efficient to use. Among those limitations:

- access to structure slots via slot names is undefined. some implementations do it, others not.
- redefining a structure definition has undefined consequences. This means that in some cases, one best restarts Lisp to do that...

The idea behind that: all operations to structures should be able to be inlined and an executing program should not need any further information about structure slots (their names, their memory locations, ...). There would be no dynamic lookup at runtime.

Then Common Lisp in general has this further limitation: it has no first class pointers. There is no mechanism to provide a pointer only pointing directly to the slot of a structure. In some older Lisp dialects this might be possible via a concept of *locatives* - pointers in those languages. Common Lisp does not support that.

This means practically: to update a slot of a structure, one needs access to the structure and a setter operation.

**How do update the slot of a structure?**

I can think of two simple ways:

- pass the structure, a new value and an indicator what to update -> then dispatch on the indicator and call the right updater

Example

```
(defun update (s indicator value)
  (case indicator
    (:a (setf (node-a s) value))
    (:b (setf (node-b s) value))))

(update tree :a (make-node :v 100))
```

- Pass a closure, which does the update

Example:

```
(let ((tree ...))
  (flet ((do-something (updater)
           (funcall updater (make-node :v 100))))
    (do-something (lambda (value) (setf (node-a tree) value) ...)))
```